mypy: typing a tuple with large number of arguments
I have the following requirement to type
n: int = 256
x: tuple[(int,) * n] = (1,) * n

mypy however fails with Type expected within [...]  [misc] - how can this be fixed
Current reading:

https://github.com/python/typing/issues/221#issuecomment-239597477
https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3345


In addition to the dupe, how are you going to use that function? Since it can't be reasonably unpacked (no one is going to introduce 256 vars, right) and is quite unlikely to be manually constructed as a literal tuple of 256 items (probably it's tuple(... for _ in range(256)) or tuple(some_data_of_known_width_256), right?..) - so the explicit annotation of a 256-tuple won't be helpful for type checking, thus just use a docstring to relay such information and tuple[int, ...] as a type hint.

yeah it's annoying because it's a complex cryptography data structure  and I wanted it typed but that's what I'm doing tuple[int, ...]
